# Erro no Scaffolding durante geração da View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Estou criando um projeto novo usando EF Power Tools e estou com o seguinte erro:

> Error 
>   There was an error running the selected code generator:
>   'A configuration for type 'TST2.Models.Course' has already been added.
>   To reference the existing configuration use the Entity() or ComplexType() methods.

Consigo contornar o erro (Gerando a View sem um context), mas preciso entender o que fiz de errado.

Segue minha entidade:

```
public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.StudentGrades = new List<StudentGrade>();
        this.People = new List<Person>();
    }

    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual OnlineCourse OnlineCourse { get; set; }
    public virtual OnsiteCourse OnsiteCourse { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StudentGrade> StudentGrades { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
}
```

Código para Mapping :

```
public class CourseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Course>
{
    public CourseMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.CourseID);

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.CourseID)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        ToTable("Course");
       Property(t => t.CourseID).HasColumnName("CourseID");
       Property(t => t.Title).HasColumnName("Title");
        Property(t => t.Credits).HasColumnName("Credits");
        Property(t => t.DepartmentID).HasColumnName("DepartmentID");

        // Relationships
        HasMany(t => t.People)
            .WithMany(t => t.Courses)
            .Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("CourseInstructor");
                    m.MapLeftKey("CourseID");
                    m.MapRightKey("PersonID");
                });

        HasRequired(t => t.Department)
            .WithMany(t => t.Courses)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentID);

    }
}
```

Código Contexto:

```
 public class SchoolContext : DbContext
 {
    static SchoolContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<SchoolContext>(null);
    }

    public SchoolContext()
        : base(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=School;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True")
    {   }

    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OfficeAssignment> OfficeAssignments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OnlineCourse> OnlineCourses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<OnsiteCourse> OnsiteCourses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentGrade> StudentGrades { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CourseMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DepartmentMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OfficeAssignmentMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OnlineCourseMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OnsiteCourseMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StudentGradeMap());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta mensagem de erro:

> 'A configuration for type 'TST2.Models.Course' has already been added. To reference the existing configuration use the Entity() or ComplexType() methods.

Quer dizer que esta configuração:

```
public class CourseMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Course>
{ ... }
```

Já existia, e que o Power Tools não irá gerá-la novamente.

É apenas uma orientação. Não uma mensagem de erro. A configuração está correta.

Comment: O Power Tools gerou esses modelos. Utilizando o scaffolding para criar uma View, aparece a mensagem de erro. Não estou tentando gerar novamente, estou criando uma View em cima do modelo do Power Tools.

Comment: Sim, mas a geração da View tenta criar a configuração novamente, possivelmente porque tenta criar algum passo com *Controller* também. Se você quer gerar só a *View*, use o *Scaffolding* do Visual Studio, que está nos menus do botão direito.

Comment: Então, é exatamente isso que vc descreveu que estou fazendo. E o erro insiste em impedir a ação. Como eu disse, se eu não selecionar um data context, ele consegue criar a View. É uma forma de contornar mas não de solucionar o erro.

Comment: Entendi. Bom, eu posso melhorar a resposta, mas você vai ter que abandonar esses arquivos de configuração da entidade.

Answer (score 3):

Isso é realmente um erro e me perturbou por um bom tempo, Eu resolvi da seguinte forma só assim funcionou comigo.
Tem que mudar onde esta assim por exemplo:

```
public DbSet<OnsiteCourse> OnsiteCourses { get; set; }
```

Para:

```
public IDbSet<OnsiteCourse> OnsiteCourses { get; set; }
```

Muda o DbSet para IDbSet depois da um **Clean** e um **Rebuild** e tenta gerar a view, que vai funcionar. Sem precisar mexer com o Mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Tente limpar o ComponentModelCache, o cache consertará no próximo rebuild.

1. Feche o Visual Studio
2. Delete a pasta ComponentModelCache
   C:\Users\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
3. Reinicie o Visual Studio

Obs: 14.0 é para versão visual studio 2015. 
Também funciona pras outras versões